# How to select an element based on a style value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I am making a custom progress bar that I want to change color based on it's `width` value. i.e if it's `width` is less than 50% the bar is red, if it's greater then the bar is green.

I know I can use the attribute selector like so:

```
.p-bar[style*="width: 10"] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

But doing it like this would mean I would have to asign a value every step of the way...

P.D. sass solutions acceptable, thanks.

**Edit**

P.P.D. js solution also acceptable... but I would like to know if there is defenetly no way to accomplish what I want with CSS.

Comment: Unless the `style` is in the HTML... **you can't**

Comment: Oh... that's discouraging. Well I just tough there was a way to make the "10" a variable or something. I'll guess I'll ask for a js solution, that would be fine too.
Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: What is the HTML/ code that's making the progress bar change?

Comment: It is easier to help if you add some more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... so as it was said before it seems like it is not possible to to do what I was trying to do using only css.
However it seems pretty easy to change color based on value using javascript.

Here is the code I ended up using (I have a button to add 10% of "progress" AKA `width` to my bar ):

```
var progressed = 0; /* Variable to handle the width % */
$('.btnAddProgress').click(function(){
    var progressBar = $(this).parent().find('.progress-bar'); /* Get the bar */
    progressed += 10;
    progressBar.css({
        'width': progressed + '%', /* Apply the changed width */
    });

var progPrcnt = progressBar.width() / progressBar.parent().width() * 100; /* Wanted to get the actual element width because I figured I would not always have a variable like my "progressed" which value matches the actual width */
if (progPrcnt < 50) {
    progressBar.css({
        'background-color': '#f00',
    });
} else {
    progressBar.css({
        'background-color': '#0f0',
    });
}
});
```

Anyways... It turns out it was fairly easy to do what I wanted to do using JS and ended up figuring it out quite soon, and then <s>not wanting</s> forgetting to come back to my post and point out how dumb I was.

Anyways as I always say I'ms still learning, thanks a lot for your help an patience.